# Java Scanner won't follow file

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, tail

Trying to tail / parse some log files. Entries start with a date then can span many lines.

This works, but does not ever see new entries to file.

```
File inputFile = new File("C:/test.txt");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
//bis.skip(inputFile.length());
Scanner src = new Scanner(bis);
src.useDelimiter("\n2010-05-01 ");

while (true) {
    while(src.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("[ " + src.next() + " ]");
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem like Scanner's next() or hasNext() detects new entries to file.

Any idea how else I can implement, basically, a tail -f with custom delimiter.

---

ok - using Kelly's advise i'm checking & refreshing the scanner, this works. Thank you !!

if anyone has improvement suggestions plz do!

```
File inputFile = new File("C:/test.txt");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
//bis.skip(inputFile.length());
Scanner src = new Scanner(bis);
src.useDelimiter("\n2010-05-01 ");

while (true) {
    while(src.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("[ " + src.next() + " ]");
    }

    Thread.sleep(50);
    if(bis.available() > 0){
    src = new Scanner(bis);
    src.useDelimiter("\n2010-05-01 ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do now, does it throw an exception or hang in an infinite loop without detecting the new data?

Comment: infinite loop without detecting the new data. tried it a bunch of ways, testing hasNext() 1st, buffered/unbuffered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the Scanner is parsing `bis` which is buffered but the buffer is never getting refreshed.  You might be relying on the BufferedInputStream or the Scanner to keep reading bytes from the stream but I think you have to do that yourself.

From the Javadocs:

> A BufferedInputStream adds
>   functionality to another input
>   stream-namely, the ability to buffer
>   the input and to support the mark and
>   reset methods. When the
>   BufferedInputStream is created, an
>   internal buffer array is created. As
>   bytes from the stream are read or
>   skipped, the internal buffer is
>   refilled as necessary from the
>   contained input stream, many bytes at
>   a time. The mark operation remembers a
>   point in the input stream and the
>   reset operation causes all the bytes
>   read since the most recent mark
>   operation to be reread before new
>   bytes are taken from the contained
>   input stream.